# C++ Output is not Correct?

Tags: c++

Overview: I am creating a C++ program to calculate area, perimeter, surface area, and volume of common 2D and 3D shapes. This program simply reads from a text file and outputs the calculations to the console and a text file. When I run the program my outputs are different than expected. When I output to the console I am getting very strange numbers (negative and numbers that do not make sense). When I output to the text file it is not displaying any calculations (only displaying the else statement "INVALID OBJECT"). Before I had to incorporate principle of least privilege (syntax that applies restrictions to what we can do in our own programs; syntax involves these C++ keywords: const and public and class; also private and protected) my program was running fine, however now my output is not working properly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class Square {
    const double squareSide;
    
public:
    void outputSquare(ostream&) const;
    Square(const vector<string>&);
    Square& operator=(const Square&);
};

Square::Square(const vector<string>& tokens)
:squareSide((tokens.size() > 1) ? atof(tokens[1].c_str( )) : 0) //intializer list
{
    
}

class Rectangle {
    const double rectangleLength;
    const double rectangleWidth;
    
public:
    void outputRectangle(ostream&) const;
    Rectangle(const vector<string>&);
    Rectangle& operator=(const Rectangle&);
};

Rectangle::Rectangle(const vector<string>& tokens)
:rectangleLength((tokens.size() > 1) ? atof(tokens[1].c_str()) : 0), rectangleWidth((tokens.size() > 2) ? atof(tokens[2].c_str()) : 0)
{
    
}

class Circle {
    const double circleRadius;
    
public:
    void outputCircle(ostream&) const;
    Circle(const vector<string>&);
    Circle& operator=(const Circle&);
};

Circle::Circle(const vector<string>& tokens)
:circleRadius((tokens.size() > 1) ? atof(tokens[1].c_str( )) : 0)
{
    
}

class Triangle {
    const double triangleSide;
    
public:
    void outputTriangle(ostream&) const;
    Triangle(const vector<string>&);
    Triangle& operator=(const Triangle&);
};

Triangle::Triangle(const vector<string>& tokens)
:triangleSide((tokens.size() > 1) ? atof(tokens[1].c_str( )) : 0)
{
    
}

class Cube {
    const double cubeSide;
    
public:
    void outputCube(ostream&) const;
    Cube(const vector<string>&);
    Cube& operator=(const Cube&);
};

Cube::Cube(const vector<string>& tokens)
:cubeSide((tokens.size() > 1) ? atof(tokens[1].c_str( )) : 0)
{
    
}

class Box {
    const double boxLength;
    const double boxWidth;
    const double boxHeight;
    
public:
    void outputBox(ostream&) const;
    Box(const vector<string>&);
    Box& operator=(const Box&);
};

Box::Box(const vector<string>& tokens)
:boxLength((tokens.size() > 1) ? atof(tokens[1].c_str()) : 0), boxWidth((tokens.size() > 2) ? atof(tokens[2].c_str()) : 0), boxHeight((tokens.size() > 3) ? atof(tokens[3].c_str()) : 0)
{
    
}

class Cylinder {
    const double cylinderRadius;
    const double cylinderHeight;
    
public:
    void outputCylinder(ostream&) const;
    Cylinder(const vector<string>&);
    Cylinder& operator=(const Cylinder&);
};

Cylinder::Cylinder(const vector<string>& tokens)
:cylinderRadius((tokens.size() > 1) ? atof(tokens[1].c_str()) : 0), cylinderHeight((tokens.size() > 2) ? atof(tokens[2].c_str()) : 0)
{
    
}

class Prism {
    const double prismSide;
    const double prismHeight;
    
public:
    void outputPrism(ostream&) const;
    Prism(const vector<string>&);
    Prism& operator=(const Prism&);
};

Prism::Prism(const vector<string>& tokens)
:prismSide((tokens.size() > 1) ? atof(tokens[1].c_str()) : 0), prismHeight((tokens.size() > 2) ? atof(tokens[2].c_str()) : 0)
{
    
}

//Prototypes
vector<string> parseString(string);
ostream& roundingTwo(ostream&);
ostream& roundingOff(ostream&);

int main () {
    
    //Bag declaration
    const vector<const void*> myBag; //stored as pointers, store memory locations in bag, (use void no specific data type)
    vector<char> myBagType; //companion array-value at each index tells what stored in the memory location bag
    
    //process input file and fill bag
    ifstream read; //read from file
    ofstream write; //write to file
    
    read.open("Shapes.input.txt"); //open read text file
    write.open("ShapesOutput.txt"); //open write text file
    if(read.good()){
        
        string line;
        
        //reading file
        while(getline(read,line)){
            
            vector<string> tokens = parseString(line);
            
            //matching strings then assigning pasrsed string variables from vector to variables
            if(tokens.size() != 0){
                
                if(tokens[0] == "SQUARE"){ //match string
                    const Square* square = new Square(tokens); //create dynamic class with read only pointer
                    const_cast<vector<const void*>&>(myBag).push_back(square); //push back square pointer that points to square
                    myBagType.push_back('S'); //push back character in myBagType(same index as myBag vector)
                }
                else if(tokens[0] == "RECTANGLE"){ //match string
                    const Rectangle* rectangle = new Rectangle(tokens);
                    const_cast<vector<const void*>&>(myBag).push_back(rectangle);
                    myBagType.push_back('R');
                }
                else if(tokens[0] == "CIRCLE"){ //match string
                    const Circle* circle = new Circle(tokens);
                    const_cast<vector<const void*>&>(myBag).push_back(circle);
                    myBagType.push_back('C');
                }
                else if(tokens[0] == "TRIANGLE"){ //match string
                    const Triangle* triangle = new Triangle(tokens);
                    const_cast<vector<const void*>&>(myBag).push_back(triangle);
                    myBagType.push_back('T');
                }
                else if(tokens[0] == "CUBE"){ //match string
                    const Cube* cube = new Cube(tokens);
                    const_cast<vector<const void*>&>(myBag).push_back(cube);
                    myBagType.push_back('U');
                }
                else if(tokens[0] == "BOX"){ //match string
                    const Box* box = new Box(tokens);
                    const_cast<vector<const void*>&>(myBag).push_back(box);;
                    myBagType.push_back('B');
                }
                else if(tokens[0] == "CYLINDER"){ //match string
                    const Cylinder* cylinder = new Cylinder(tokens);
                    const_cast<vector<const void*>&>(myBag).push_back(cylinder);
                    myBagType.push_back('Y');
                }
                else if(tokens[0] == "PRISM"){ //match string
                    const Prism* prism = new Prism(tokens);
                    const_cast<vector<const void*>&>(myBag).push_back(prism);
                    myBagType.push_back('P');
                }
                else{
                    cout << tokens[0] << " INVALID object" << endl;
                    write << tokens[0] << " INVALID object" << endl;
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    read.close(); //close read file
    write.close(); //close write file
    
    //sort objects
    for(int i = 0; i < myBag.size(); i++)
        for(int j = i + 1; j < myBag.size(); j++)
            if(myBagType[j] < myBagType[i])
                swap(myBagType[i], myBagType[j]);

    
    //output to console
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < myBag.size(); i++){ //for loop to go through entire myBag size
        
        if(myBagType[i] == 'S') //if at myBagType index character equals letter
        {
            const Square* const pSquare = reinterpret_cast<const Square*>(myBag[i]); //restore Square
            const Square& rSquare = *pSquare; // dereference the pointer to match the function's parameter
            rSquare.outputSquare(cout); //call member function
        }
        else if(myBagType[i] == 'R')
        {
            const Rectangle* const pRectangle = reinterpret_cast<const Rectangle*>(myBag[i]);
            const Rectangle& rRectangle = *pRectangle;
            rRectangle.outputRectangle(cout);
        }
        else if(myBagType[i] == 'C')
        {
            const Circle* const pCircle = reinterpret_cast<const Circle*>(myBag[i]);
            const Circle& rCricle = *pCircle;
            rCricle.outputCircle(cout);
        }
        else if(myBagType[i] == 'T')
        {
            const Triangle* const pTriangle = reinterpret_cast<const Triangle*>(myBag[i]);
            const Triangle& rTriangle = *pTriangle;
            rTriangle.outputTriangle(cout);
        }
        else if(myBagType[i] == 'U')
        {
            const Cube* const pCube = reinterpret_cast<const Cube*>(myBag[i]);
            const Cube& rCube = *pCube;
            rCube.outputCube(cout);
        }
        else if(myBagType[i] == 'B')
        {
            const Box* const pBox = reinterpret_cast<const Box*>(myBag[i]);
            const Box& rBox = *pBox;
            rBox.outputBox(cout);
        }
        else if(myBagType[i] == 'Y')
        {
            const Cylinder* const pCylinder = reinterpret_cast<const Cylinder*>(myBag[i]);
            const Cylinder& rCylinder = *pCylinder;
            rCylinder.outputCylinder(cout);
        }
        else if(myBagType[i] == 'P')
        {
            const Prism* const pPrism = reinterpret_cast<const Prism*>(myBag[i]);
            const Prism& rPrism = *pPrism;
            rPrism.outputPrism(cout);
        }
        else{
            cout << "EMPTY" << endl;
        }
    }

    //output to text file
    //program enters loop
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < myBag.size(); i++){
        if(myBagType[i] == 'S')
        {
            const Square* const pSquare = reinterpret_cast<const Square*>(myBag[i]); //restore Square
            const Square& rSquare = *pSquare; // dereference the pointer to match the function's parameter
            rSquare.outputSquare(write); //call member function
        }
        else if(myBagType[i] == 'R')
        {
            const Rectangle* const pRectangle = reinterpret_cast<const Rectangle*>(myBag[i]);
            const Rectangle& rRectangle = *pRectangle;
            rRectangle.outputRectangle(write);
        }
        else if(myBagType[i] == 'C')
        {
            const Circle* const pCircle = reinterpret_cast<const Circle*>(myBag[i]);
            const Circle& rCricle = *pCircle;
            rCricle.outputCircle(write);
        }
        else if(myBagType[i] == 'T')
        {
            const Triangle* const pTriangle = reinterpret_cast<const Triangle*>(myBag[i]);
            const Triangle& rTriangle = *pTriangle;
            rTriangle.outputTriangle(write);
        }
        else if(myBagType[i] == 'U')
        {
            const Cube* const pCube = reinterpret_cast<const Cube*>(myBag[i]);
            const Cube& rCube = *pCube;
            rCube.outputCube(write);
        }
        else if(myBagType[i] == 'B')
        {
            const Box* const pBox = reinterpret_cast<const Box*>(myBag[i]);
            const Box& rBox = *pBox;
            rBox.outputBox(write);
        }
        else if(myBagType[i] == 'Y')
        {
            const Cylinder* const pCylinder = reinterpret_cast<const Cylinder*>(myBag[i]);
            const Cylinder& rCylinder = *pCylinder;
            rCylinder.outputCylinder(write);
        }
        else if(myBagType[i] == 'P')
        {
            const Prism* const pPrism = reinterpret_cast<const Prism*>(myBag[i]);
            const Prism& rPrism = *pPrism;
            rPrism.outputPrism(write);
        }
        else{
            cout << "EMPTY" << endl;
        }
    }
    
    //deallocation
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < myBag.size(); i++){
        if(myBagType[i] == 'S')
        {
            const Square* const pSquare = reinterpret_cast<const Square*>(myBag[i]);
            delete pSquare;
        }
        else if(myBagType[i] == 'R')
        {
            const Rectangle* const pRectangle = reinterpret_cast<const Rectangle*>(myBag[i]);
            delete pRectangle;
        }
        else if(myBagType[i] == 'C')
        {
            const Circle* const pCircle = reinterpret_cast<const Circle*>(myBag[i]);
            delete pCircle;
        }
        else if(myBagType[i] == 'T')
        {
            const Triangle* pTriangle = reinterpret_cast<const Triangle*>(myBag[i]);
            delete pTriangle;
        }
        else if(myBagType[i] == 'U')
        {
            const Cube* const pCube = reinterpret_cast<const Cube*>(myBag[i]);
            delete pCube;
        }
        else if(myBagType[i] == 'B')
        {
            const Box* const pBox = reinterpret_cast<const Box*>(myBag[i]);
            delete pBox;
        }
        else if(myBagType[i] == 'Y')
        {
            const Cylinder* const pCylinder = reinterpret_cast<const Cylinder*>(myBag[i]);
            delete pCylinder;
        }
        else if(myBagType[i] == 'P')
        {
            const Prism* const pPrism = reinterpret_cast<const Prism*>(myBag[i]);
            delete pPrism;
        }
        else{
            cout << "EMPTY" << endl;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}

//parse string function
vector<string> parseString(string str)
{
    stringstream s(str);
    istream_iterator<string> begin(s), end;
    return vector<string>(begin, end);
}

//turn on rounding function
ostream& roundingTwo(ostream& out)
{
    out.setf(ios::fixed);
    out.precision(2); // 2 decimal digits
    return out;
}

//turn off rounding function
ostream& roundingOff(ostream& out)
{
    out.unsetf(ios::fixed);
    out.precision(6); // the C++ default
    return out;
}

//output function
void Square::outputSquare(ostream& out) const
{
    double squareArea = squareSide * squareSide;
    double squarePerimeter = 4 * squareSide;
    
    //display data
    out << roundingOff << "SQUARE"<< " Side = " << squareSide <<  " Area = " << roundingTwo << squareArea << "  Perimeter = " << squarePerimeter << roundingOff << endl;
}

void Rectangle::outputRectangle(ostream& out) const
{
    double rectangleArea = rectangleLength * rectangleWidth;
    double rectanglePerimeter = (2 * rectangleLength) + (2 * rectangleWidth);
    
    //display data
    out << roundingOff << "RECTANGLE"<< " Length = " << rectangleLength << " Width = " << rectangleWidth << " Area = " << roundingTwo << rectangleArea << " Perimeter = " << rectanglePerimeter << roundingOff << endl;
}

void Circle::outputCircle(ostream& out) const
{
    double circleArea = M_PI * (circleRadius * circleRadius);
    double circlePerimeter = 2 * M_PI * circleRadius;
    
    //display data
    out << roundingOff << "CIRCLE" << " Radius = " << circleRadius <<  " Area = " << roundingTwo << circleArea << " Perimeter = " << circlePerimeter << roundingOff << endl;
}

void Triangle::outputTriangle(ostream& out) const
{
    double triangleArea = (sqrt(3.0) / 4) * (triangleSide * triangleSide);
    double trianglePerimeter = 3 * triangleSide;
    
    //display data
    out << roundingOff << "TRIANGLE" << " Side = " << triangleSide <<  " Area = " << roundingTwo << triangleArea << " Perimeter = " << trianglePerimeter << roundingOff << endl;
}

void Cube::outputCube(ostream& out) const
{
    double cubeSurfaceArea = 6 * (cubeSide * cubeSide);
    double cubeVolume = cubeSide * cubeSide * cubeSide;
    
    //display data
    out << roundingOff << "CUBE" << " Side = " << cubeSide <<  " Surface Area = " << roundingTwo << cubeSurfaceArea << " Volume = " << cubeVolume << roundingOff << endl;
}

void Box::outputBox(ostream& out) const
{
    double boxSurfaceArea = (2 * boxLength * boxWidth) + (2 * boxLength * boxHeight) + (2 * boxHeight * boxWidth);
    double boxVolume = boxLength * boxWidth * boxHeight;
    
    //display data
    out << roundingOff << "BOX" << " Length = " << boxLength << " Width = " << boxWidth << " Height = " << boxHeight << " Surface Area = " << roundingTwo << boxSurfaceArea << " Volume = " << boxVolume << roundingOff << endl;
}

void Cylinder::outputCylinder(ostream& out) const
{
    double cylinderSurfaceArea = (2 * M_PI * cylinderRadius * cylinderHeight) + (2 * M_PI * (cylinderRadius * cylinderRadius));
    double cylinderVolume = M_PI * (cylinderRadius * cylinderRadius) * cylinderHeight;
    
    //display data
    out << roundingOff << "CYLINDER" << " Radius = " << cylinderRadius << " Height = " << cylinderHeight << " Surface Area = " << roundingTwo << cylinderSurfaceArea << " Volume = " << cylinderVolume << roundingOff << endl;
}

void Prism::outputPrism(ostream& out) const
{
    double prismSurfaceArea = (sqrt(3.0) / 2) * (prismSide * prismSide) + (3 * prismSide * prismHeight);
    double prismVolume = (sqrt(3.0) / 4) * (prismSide * prismSide) * prismHeight;
    
    //display data
    out << roundingOff << "PRISM" << " Side = " << prismSide << " Height = " << prismHeight << " Surface Area = " << roundingTwo << prismSurfaceArea << " Volume = " << prismVolume << roundingOff << endl;
}

// the assignment operator
Square& Square::operator=(const Square& copyThis) //parameter is a constant reference
{
    Square& host = *this; //reference to host object
    
    if(this != &copyThis) //skips self copy if host and paramter are same object
    {
        const_cast<double&>(host.squareSide) = copyThis.squareSide;
    }
    return host; //returns a self reference
}

Rectangle& Rectangle::operator=(const Rectangle& copyThis)
{
    Rectangle& host = *this;
    
    if(this != &copyThis)
    {
        const_cast<double&>(host.rectangleWidth) = copyThis.rectangleWidth;
        const_cast<double&>(host.rectangleLength) = copyThis.rectangleLength;
    }
    return host;
}

Circle& Circle::operator=(const Circle& copyThis)
{
    Circle& host = *this;
    
    if(this != &copyThis)
    {
        const_cast<double&>(host.circleRadius) = copyThis.circleRadius;
    }
    return host;
}

Triangle& Triangle::operator=(const Triangle& copyThis)
{
    Triangle& host = *this;
    
    if(this != &copyThis)
    {
        const_cast<double&>(host.triangleSide) = copyThis.triangleSide;
    }
    return host;
}

Cube& Cube::operator=(const Cube& copyThis)
{
    Cube& host = *this;
    
    if(this != &copyThis)
    {
        const_cast<double&>(host.cubeSide) = copyThis.cubeSide;
    }
    return host;
}

Box& Box::operator=(const Box& copyThis)
{
    Box& host = *this;
    
    if(this != &copyThis)
    {
        const_cast<double&>(host.boxLength) = copyThis.boxLength;
        const_cast<double&>(host.boxWidth) = copyThis.boxWidth;
        const_cast<double&>(host.boxHeight) = copyThis.boxHeight;
    }
    return host;
}

Cylinder& Cylinder::operator=(const Cylinder& copyThis)
{
    Cylinder& host = *this;
    
    if(this != &copyThis)
    {
        const_cast<double&>(host.cylinderRadius) = copyThis.cylinderRadius;
        const_cast<double&>(host.cylinderHeight) = copyThis.cylinderHeight;
    }
    return host;
}

Prism& Prism::operator=(const Prism& copyThis)
{
    Prism& host = *this;
    
    if(this != &copyThis)
    {
        const_cast<double&>(host.prismSide) = copyThis.prismSide;
        const_cast<double&>(host.prismHeight) = copyThis.prismHeight;
    }
    return host;
}
```

Comment: There is too much code try to reduce it to a [mcve]. You also didn't post the text file you're reading, post a minimal text file that shows the problem.

Comment: One thing: You have made the member variables `const` and then have to `const_cast` away the `const` all the time. That should tell you that the member variables should _not_ be `const`. If you make them non-`const` you don't even have to be writing your own assignment operators. The implicitly defined will work out of the box...

Comment: After a fast look, I have the feeling that your code could be highly simplified with inheritance.

Comment: I made the member variables non-`const` and removed all your assignment operators ([here](https://godbolt.org/z/jrf4ffGdP)) - but still 7% of your code contain cast's in different ways. Nothing in what you are trying to do should require a single cast from what I can see.